# Bash (Text extracting)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have this very long line of info in 1 file, and i want to extract it, so that the end result look like this output.txt ? Please help !

My input looks like:

```
[{"city":"london","first name":"peter","last name":"hansen","age":"40"},
{"city":"new york","first name":"celine","last name":"parker","age":"36"]
```

Output.txt

```
peter (40)
celine (36)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a closing curly brace right before the closing square bracket?

Answer (score 1):

If it is proper json, an alternative is to use `jq`:

```
$ cat test.json
[{"city":"london","first name":"peter","last name":"hansen","age":"40"},
  {"city":"new york","first name":"celine","last name":"parker","age":"36"}]

$ jq -r '.[] | "\(."first name") (\(.age))"' test.json
peter (40)
celine (36)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input string is stored in a file *input.txt*, i.e.

```
echo '[{"city":"london","first name":"peter","last name":"hansen","age":"40"},{"city":"new york","first name":"celine","last name":"parker","age":"36"}]' >input.txt
```

you can get the result by

```
ruby -e "puts $(<input.txt).map {|x| %(#{x[:'first name']} (#{x[:age]}))}"
```

(This uses the fact that the input happens to be a syntactically valid Ruby expression, denoting an array of two hashes).